# php - Show last value + 1 on select>option

Tags: php, mysql

I have table "pages" and have 4 positions.
My question is how I am going to show value of "5" on select option instead of showing all positions from 1 - 5.

Image Example:

Instead of

[image]

It should only show:

[image]

```
function get_all_arjay_pages_desc(){
    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM pages
              ORDER BY position DESC";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    validate_query($result);

    return $result;
}


echo "<select name='position' id=''>";
        $get_all_page = get_all_arjay_pages_desc();
        $page_counts = mysql_num_rows($get_all_page);

        for($count=1; $count <= $page_counts + 1;$count++){
            echo "<option value='{$count}'>{$count}</option>";
        }

        echo "</select>";
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for last value of `$count` and add selected

```
for($count=1; $count <= $page_counts + 1;$count++){
            $sel = ($count == ($page_counts + 1)) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
            echo "<option value='{$count}'$sel>{$count}</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `selected` attribute, e .g.

```
for($count=1; $count <= $page_counts + 1;$count++){
    $selected = ($count == 5) ? ' selected="selected"' : '';
    echo "<option value='{$count}'$selected>{$count}</option>";
}
```

So when $count hits 5, you'll get

```
<option value='5' selected="selected">5</option>
```